# Trying to Get Data using Ajax call to Controller method MVC My code Attached

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am calling jquery function on dropdown value change jquery method is ,

```
function MyFunction() {
    alert($('#DDlSurvey').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetSelectedQuestion", "ConductSurveyController")",
        data: { prefix: $('#DDlSurvey').val() },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        //  loadData(data);
        alert(data)
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
});
  //$('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
}
</script>
```

Function I'm calling and I am getting dropdown value alert

Now, Function that I am calling is "`GetSelectedQuestion`" in controller "`ConductSurveyController`"

Method is like ,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetSelectedQuestion(int prefix)
{
    List<SelectList> Questions=new List<SelectList>();

   //  Here "MyDatabaseEntities " is dbContext, which is created at time of model creation.
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();
       // Questions = ObjectSur.Surveys.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(prefix)).toToList();
```

I don't think this method is calling as I am getting error

> "`Failed! Please try again`"

From  my script.

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

```
 var e = from q in ObjectSur.Questions
         join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
         select q ;
         return new JsonResult { Data = e, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: What http status code is being returned for that request? _Check Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using controller name straight forward. your ajax code be something like this.

```
var PostData= { prefix: $('#DDlSurvey').val() }
var ajaxOptions = {
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSelectedQuestion", "ConductSurvey")',//Actionname, ControllerName
        data: PostData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
};
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

Comment: true man i just finished it with same changes you posted anyways thanks

Comment: Sorry i misunderstand issue is same as you said but i tried simple method in controller instead one i mentioned in post after making same changes still getting same error perhaps there is error in linq or given method ? how can i check linq

Comment: remove all code and just return simple string message from your MVC controller

Answer (score 1):

Your method in your controller is decorated with `HttpPost`, while in your ajax you have specified the type of your request is `get` . You can either change your method to get like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSelectedQuestion(int prefix)
{
}
```

Or change your request type to post in your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetSelectedQuestion", "ConductSurveyController")",
    data: { prefix: $('#DDlSurvey').val() },
    type: "Post",
```

Also the `Controller` is redundant in `ConductSurveyController`, you need to remove it and simply call it as `ConductSurvey`:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetSelectedQuestion", "ConductSurvey")',
```