# Ajax Call to pass the data from view to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can i pass a data in textbox to controller using ajax call in C# MVC. I have got examples to pass data to the string method but i wanted to pass the data to Action Result, Can any one help me to pass the data in the textbox to my Action Result method in controller.

Comment: please share snippet of code. and your requirement is you want to pass textbox value to your action method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the `@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", method))`, in MVC 5 there exists `@using(Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", method))`. You can find the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

If you want the API call to be done in the background you'll also need to install [jquery ajax unobstrusive](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive).

If you need a more concrete example, there is a similar StackOverflow question [17095443](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096835/8175277). This answer explains it better than I ever could.

Answer (score 0):

A simple syntax of ajax call to your controller is

```
<input type='text' id='id1' />

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', // 'NameController/GetNameUsingAjax'
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { name: $('#id1').val() }, // 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { alert('Success'); },
    error: function() { alert('error'); }
});
```

C# code is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetNameUsingAjax(string name)
{
    return Json("Ajax Success + " + name);
}
```

Comment: more reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519218/trying-to-get-data-using-ajax-call-to-controller-method-mvc-my-code-attached/53520034#53520034