# Set Query Results as Source for DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to set the source of my datatable to the data returned from my stored procedure.  This is my code, but my DataTable is not populated.  Can someone please assist me with updating this code so the DataTable is populated with the stored procedure results?

> This is my JavaScript

```
$("#btnClick").click(function () {
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: getURL,
        method: "GET"
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "Location" },
        { data: "TC" }
    ]
});
});
```

> This is my HTML

```
<div id="table1">
    <table id="example" class="display">
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="btnClick">Button One</button>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var getURL = '@Url.Action("GTC")';
    </script>
}
```

> This is my Controller Code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/EmpCheck")]
public class EmpCheckController : Controller
{
    EmpCheck _context;

    public EmpCheckController( context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var VerifyAllEmpsOnDuty = _context.EmpCheckModel.FromSql("_GetClockedInEmps").ToList();
        return View(VerifyAllEmpsOnDuty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of data returned by your server-side script?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - how can I check that/

Comment: Hi James, will you include the code for your controller that contains the action "GTC"? Your script mentions; `var getURL = @Url.Action("GTC")` but the code you posted doesn't contain any action with GTC as its name.

Comment: @jamesh when you bind data table With server binding prepare JSON results with respect data table output.

Comment: @jamesh please check this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jquery-datatable-server-side-processing-with-custom-operations/

Comment: check your API is working fine or not.

Comment: @NegiRox - yes the API is working as it should be

Comment: then make ajax call after getting response use that response to construct your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly bind ajax source to datatable. if your API is working fine.

```
you can do it by two way.

1- directly bind ajax source.

2- fetch record using ajax and then bind response to DataTable.
```

Here is working example for [both](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/tpaLe3k1/14/)

Comment: how do I get my api?  Is that what I set as the Route for my Controller?  Like the below...[Route("api/employee-information")]

Comment: if I navigate to https://localhost:44328/api/employee-information
I get the below error.  The index.cshtml that I want to use is located at /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/EmployeeInformation/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml`

Comment: Refer this to fetch data using controller..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519218/trying-to-get-data-using-ajax-call-to-controller-method-mvc-my-code-attached

Comment: I'm testing locally and using localhost I get this error....
`jquery.js:9600 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:44328/api/employee-information?_=1571167579427' from origin 'https://localhost:44328' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` --- and I am accessing a server that is offsite, meaning not on my LAN

Comment: I made the chnages as you suggest.  I have stepped through my code and verified that I am having data returned from my api.  But when the DataTable loads, I get this error?  `DataTables warning: table id=data - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: @JamesL map your object keys with table column

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one For more details [Click here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)

> cshtml page

```
<div id="table1">
    <table id="example" class="display">
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="btnClick">Button One</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Controller Code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/EmpCheck")]
public class EmpCheckController : Controller
{
    EmpCheck _context;

    public EmpCheckController( context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {        
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult LoadDataTable()
    {
        var VerifyAllEmpsOnDuty = _context.EmpCheckModel.FromSql("_GetClockedInEmps").ToList();

        return Json(new  
        {                      
            recordsTotal = VerifyAllEmpsOnDuty.Count(),                      
            data = VerifyAllEmpsOnDuty  
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }
}
```

> Javascript code

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var getURL = '@Url.Action("LoadDataTable","EmpCheck")';
        This is my JavaScript
        $("#btnClick").click(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: getURL,
                    method: "GET"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "Location" },
                    { data: "TC" }
                ]
            });
        });
});
    </script>
}
```

Comment: do you have the Javascript in the index.cshtml or do you have it in the site.js?  I ask bc you use the @section tag

Comment: I get an error 'the name JSONRequestBehaviour does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ok, you have created an MVC project or API project?

Comment: This is a MVC Project

Comment: Ok, So please check ` Newtonsoft.Json` package in your project if it's not there, please install

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid JSON response error....http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Yes, I have Newtonsoft JSON added from NuGet

Comment: Is there a way I can view my JSON response in the Console.Log() so I can see what format it is in?

Comment: Yes you see your response in console or `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourdata))`